# Is GLOW inspired by a real-life show?

Tags: realism, reference, glow

On Netflix's original series [*GLOW*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLOW_(TV_series)), a down-in-the-dumps director along with a young, inexperienced producer hire several unpopular actresses and work hard to make wrestling history. Has a similar phenomenon occurred in real life? If not in such dire situations, has such a show at least existed?

Answer (score 6):

## Yes

> Gorgeous Ladies of Wrestling, also known as GLOW or G.L.O.W., was a women's professional wrestling promotion begun in 1986 (the pilot was filmed in December 1985) and continued in various forms after it left television. Colorful characters, strong women, and over-the-top comedy sketches were integral to the series' success. **Most of the performers were actresses, models, dancers or stunt women hoping to enter show business.**
>
> McLane went to Hollywood, posting casting notices in The Hollywood Reporter and Variety. **Over 500 women showed up to audition at Gold's Gym. From that group, a dozen women began six weeks of training in a gym** at 108th and Broadway in Watts, Los Angeles. Mando Guerrero initially trained the women before McLane brought in wrestling veteran Cynthia Peretti, known in wrestling as Princess Jasmine, to do the training. Peretti also wrestled as the character known as Pepper.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorgeous_Ladies_of_Wrestling)

Comment: Thanks! The year also helped me find this link:http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0252462/ 
Embarrassed I didn't find it before.